# Joomla newsletter module for my application

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, newsletter

I am looking for a newsletter module for my Joomla based site. I checked at Joomla Extension Forum but did not find any suitable component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try ACYMailing component: http://www.acyba.com/en/acymailing.html . I have been using it for 2 years. Scheduling tasks and grouping users are really helpful features you will enjoy

Answer (score 3):

You can give a try to 
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/content-sharing/newsletter/10341

also if you are familiar with [Mailchimp](http://mailchimp.com)  and want to integrate with joomla them 
[Joomlamailer](http://www.joomlamailer.com)  will be best for you.

Comment: I'll second the Mailchimp/Joomailer suggestion. It is a very good component and Mailchimp has great service at a great price.

Comment: @BrentFriar Thank you for you time, but m looking for a non-commercial module

Comment: @sfshah  mailchimp also provides free account with Up to 2,000 subscribers and 12000 emails per month.
If that meets your requirement you can go for the free account.

Comment: @sfshah both the Joomailer mailchimp integration and the Mailchimp account are free as Anand mentioned. If your list is larger than that then it shouldn't be an issue to spend $10/month for a full account. http://www.joomlamailer.com/Getting-started/ (first option)

Comment: @Anand, thanks for your help. i was trying to use joomlamailer, can not get how to create list... when i click the button "add users to list" it gives an alert message saying "Calendar.setup:
  Nothing to setup (no fields found).  Please check your code"

Comment: @BrentFriar please have a look above comment

Comment: List creation is not supported by mailchimp api , so first you have to create a list in Mailchimp itself.